# Drawing Separate Domains for Axes under Multiple Small Barcharts in D3.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, svg

My intention is to draw multiple small barcharts in one svg with different domains, building upon [the example](http://bl.ocks.org/officeofjane/7315455).

The main problem I am stuck on seems to be the problem of extracting values for a particular key from the output of `d3.nest` and defining the domain corresponding to each key. The problem arises when plotting all the values, for which the dates are drawn in the domain. Since not each key has a value corresponding to all possible dates, there is a tail plotted on the right, which breaks the order. Could you please tell me how it can be fixed, how can the inputs without a corresponding output be removed from the plotted set of values?

Here is the result:

https://plnkr.co/edit/KUnMSfJwWan3JaIpZutZ/

The data is in the following form:

```
CSC     20160919    4.0
MAT     20160923    16.0
```

In the example sample of data given, there are two dates, and two dates are going to be plotted for each small subgraph. It would be great to separate the dates corresponding to a particular key in such a way that only those dates for which there is a corresponding score are plotted.

There is a deficiency: the domains must be separate, while in the example above they are not. 
Could you please tell me how I can plot the graphs for each key with the `date` corresponding to a particular `key` as defined in `d3.nest`?

The relevant part of the code seems to be here:

```
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
```

and here:

```
 svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(function(d) {return d.values;})
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.score); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.score); })
    .attr("fill", function(d) {return color(d.score)})
```

---

### APPENDIX

The following questions can be useful:

[D3.js binding an object to data and appending for each key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923942/d3-js-binding-an-object-to-data-and-appending-for-each-key)

[X,Y domain data-binding in multiple grouped bar charts in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130411/x-y-domain-data-binding-in-multiple-grouped-bar-charts-in-d3-js?rq=1)

You can also find the following links helpful:

[Grouped Bar Chart](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051)

[Tutorial: Grouped Bar Chart](https://www.dashingd3js.com/lessons/basic-chart-grouped-bar-chart)

[Grouping Data](http://learnjsdata.com/group_data.html)

---

**HYPOTHESES**

---

Can we nest the data twice, first by course, then by date, and then plot keys' keys on the axes? Is nesting the best way to approach the problem at all?

Comment: It's very hard to help you without the CSV. Instead of a fiddle, create a plunker, where you can link your CSV file.

Comment: Dear Gerardo, I have edited the post to add the link to the plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/KUnMSfJwWan3JaIpZutZ/ . I am sorry for the inconvenience. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. And kudos for the *appendix*!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution (warning: I'm the first one to admit that my code is too complicated. Let's see if someone else comes with a simpler solution).

First, we create an empty object:

```
var xScale = {};
```

And populate this new object with two functions, one for each different scale.

```
courses.forEach(function(d) {
    xScale[d.key] = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1)
        .domain(d.values.map(function(e) {
            return e.date
        }));
});
```

After this, we'll have two different scales:

```
xScale.HIS//this is the scale for the first SVG
xScale.PHY//this is the scale for the second SVG
```

Now you can use those scales in your bars, but not directly. We have to define what scale is going to be used in what SVG.

To do that, firstly, we'll get the `key` property in the data for each SVG, and then using this value to access the correct object inside `xScale`, which contains the proper scale:

```
.attr("x", function(d) {
        var scale = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().key;
        return xScale[scale](d.date);
    })
    .attr("width", function() {
        var scale = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().key;
        return xScale[scale].rangeBand()
    })
```

The most complicated part is calling the axes. Here, we'll use `each` to call `xAxis` two times, using the first argument (the datum) to get the value of `key`:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .each(function(d) {
        return d3.select(this).call(xAxis.scale(xScale[d.key]))
            .selectAll("text")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-.8em")
            .attr("dy", "-.55em")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");
    })
```

All together, this is your updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/XFKzQm0zp0MkhzK4Qt5d?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much for such a helpful answer -- a lot to learn from you! As you wish, I will wait before accepting your answer, although I would be happy to do it straight away!