# D3.JS - Different axes for different domains for small multiples

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, svg, axes

I'm building a small multiples forked off this source [here](http://bl.ocks.org/emagee/1846f73fe4ca941c6662). Very much like this example here - my data has different categories and a number associated with it. However I would like different axes for different charts and I have trouble setting in the domain of the Y axis.

The CSV looks like this:

```
year,category,number
January 2018,Core,6.19
February 2018,Core,5.38
March 2018,Core,4.44
January 2018,MerchandiseExports,9.1
February 2018,MerchandiseExports,4.48
March 2018,MerchandiseExports,-0.66'
```

I nest the csv on the basis of categories.

```
 // Nest data by subject.
    var categories = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.category; })
        .entries(data);
```

I calculate the maximum and minimum among these categories for the domain.

```
    categories.forEach(function(s) {
        s.max = d3.max(s.values, function(d) { return d.number; });
        s.min = d3.min(s.values, function(d) { return d.number; });
    });
```

I append a line path

```
svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) { y.domain([d.min - d.min / 5, d.max + d.min / 5]); return line(d.values); });
```

I'm stuck in figuring out the logic for the setting of the y axis.

```
yScale =  d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]).domain(#What I'm missing)
```

Since I've already calculated the min and max of each category, that should be going into the domain. However, I have not figured the logic of sending the specific category domain to the domain variable. Like in the case of category 6.19 is the max, and 4.44 is the min. How do I send that to the domain?

I looked up several possible solutions, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41786764/drawing-separate-domains-for-axes-under-multiple-small-barcharts-in-d3-js) is the one that seemed promising - but I didn't understand this.

Answer (score -1):

When you need to draw the y-axis, don't use `call()` but `each()` and in the callback modify the scale and call the yAxis.

```
svg.append("g").attr("id", "yAxisG")
   .each( function (s) {
       var svg1 = d3.select(this);
       var d = svg1.datum();
       yScale.domain([d.min, d.max]);
       svg1.call(yAxis);
   });
```

Comment: Thank you! This works! But I'm unsure of how the data in the json goes to variable d through datum. The setting of the domain and then calling individually for each svg makes sense.